# Adding a textBox inside a RibbonButton in a WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a WPF.  I'm using a ribbon in the WPF.  Is there a way to create a RibbonButton that has a textBlock inside of it?  Here is the code I'm using.  I'd like to place a textBlock  inside the baggerActiveBtn.

```
<Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        Margin="81,23,-81,77"
        Grid.RowSpan="2">
  <RibbonTab Header="Home"
             KeyTip="H">
    <!-- Home  group-->
    <RibbonGroup x:Name="MenuGroup">
      <RibbonButton Name="baggerActiveBtn"
                    Height="67"
                    Margin="368,36,86,0"
                    MouseOverBorderBrush="#FFFFC500"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    Click="test123">

        <RibbonButton.MouseOverBackground>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                               StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC500"
                          Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </RibbonButton.MouseOverBackground>

      </RibbonButton>
    </RibbonGroup>
  </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the `Template` of your `Button`.

First thing, include this xmlns in your XAML file:

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
```

Right click your `Button`, `Edit Template -> Edit a Copy...`
This is a snippet of the template you should work on:

```
...<Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
                    <Image x:Name="PART_Image" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Height="32" Margin="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=LargeImageMargin, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Ribbon}}}" Source="{TemplateBinding LargeImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <RibbonTwoLineText x:Name="TwoLineText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="13" Margin="1,1,1,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Border>...
```

You should place you `TextBlock` inside the `StackPanel` or `Grid` to make it as you wish.
With this code you can insert whatever Control you like.

This should at least guide you!
Good luck.

Comment: Every time select Edit a Copy, I get an error that says Copy Template failed.

I've tried every option and combination of options but keep getting the error.  Can RibbonButtons be edited?

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention that you should include this xmlns in your xaml: `xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"`