# how to underline a character of ribbonbutton label?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any way to make a character of  ribbon button's label property to underline(underscore) in c# in order to show the access key without using the key tip property.

Eg: If it's a save button then the ribbon button label must be like Save with an underscore or underline below S.

Comment: Can you set font style?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19169578/1095741 . You'll need to edit the template of the RibbonButton to incorporate an actual Label/TextBlock that you can style as required, or alternatively just restyle the RibbonTwoLineText element.

Comment: Its breaking standard UX guidelines. Best to let the user hit the Alt key like most other Ribbon applications conform to. They will need to use the Alt key anyway, so its not like they will have extra work to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Underline` in a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlockSave">
  <Underline>S</Underline>ave
</TextBlock>
```

or,

```
textBlockSave.Inlines.Add(new Underline(new Run("S")));
textBlockSave.Inlines.Add(new Run("ave"));
```

Add this textblock `textBlockSave` as `Button` Content.